# How to use a server with multiple IP address?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have a server-process that listen to a specific port (say 60000), and my linux box has two ip-address (say ip1, and ip2).

Can I somehow start two processes in my linux box, such that Process1 can receive all packets sent to ip1:60000 and Process2 can receive all packets sent to ip2:60000.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You'll want to use the `bind` system call on the listening socket that specifies the listening IP address, instead of the (more usual) INADDR_ANY. [Reference 1]

Then, use one IP address in one process, and one IP address in the second process.  Both will be able to share the same listening port.

---

References:

1. http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/bindapi.html